# File with JavaScript in Textbox (ZK)

Tags: javascript, textbox, zk

I would like to move this code below to a file so I can reuse it in more Textboxes without copying the same code, just putting the source of the file in the Textbox tag. Is it possible? Thanks.

```
<textbox id="TBIdFunc" xmlns:w="client">                                            
  <attribute w:name="doKeyDown_">
    <![CDATA[
      function (evt) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
          if( keyCode == 8 // back space
            || keyCode == 13 // enter
            || keyCode == 16 // enter
            || (keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40) // home, end, arrows
            || keyCode == 46) { // Delete
             this.$doKeyDown_(evt);
          } else if ( !evt.shiftKey &&  // only do without shift key
            (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {// teclas A-Z   
             this.$doKeyDown_(evt);   
          } else {               
             evt.stop();
             return;
          }
       }
   ]]>
 </attribute>
</textbox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract that function into a `js` file, load this file in zul, and then reference your method. Let's simplify you example:

```
<textbox xmlns:w="client">                                            
  <attribute w:name="doKeyDown_">
    <![CDATA[
      function (evt) {
        console.log('oh hai!');
        this.$doKeyDown_(evt);
      }
   ]]>
 </attribute>
</textbox>
```

First, create a file `keyDown.js` in your webapp folder:

```
function customKeyDown(evt) {
    console.log('oh hai!');
    this.$doKeyDown_(evt);
}
```

Then your zul becomes this:

```
<script src="keyDown.js" />
<textbox xmlns:w="client" w:doKeyDown_="customKeyDown" />
```

---

If you want to shorten your textbox definition even further, you can introduce a marker sclass `customKeyDown` (or a `custom-attribute`) and use `zk.afterLoad()` and `zk.override()` to override `doKeyDown_` in general:

```
zk.afterLoad('zul.inp', function applyCustomKeyDown() {
    var xTextbox = {};
    zk.override(zul.inp.Textbox.prototype, xTextbox , {
        doKeyDown_: function (evt) {
            if (jq(this).is('.customKeyDown')) {
                console.log('oh hai!');
                xTextbox.doKeyDown_.apply(this,arguments); // call original
            } else {
                xTextbox.doKeyDown_.apply(this,arguments); // call original
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the zul, you would then only apply that sclass:

```
<textbox sclass="customKeyDown" />
```